# How to connect or link to localhost server address in Android Studio

Tags: php, android, mysql, server

I am following a tutorial of making a login register for android by *tonakami TV* in youtube, I encountered a problem where the android app can't update or connect to the database via LOCALHOST XAMPP. For one week I'm stuck searching all possible solution but found none. Perhaps you guys can help me with the problem of my PHP files(**register.php** and **fetchuserdata.php**), I also found out that I also have this error in the php files: **mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1044): Access denied for user 'my_user'@'localhost' to database 'my_db'**. I grant all privileges but still can't connect and I don't know if the problem is from the PHP files, the link to the server in android studio or of XAMPP localhost phpmyadmin. Thanks !

[Screenshot of Android Studio: highlighted link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGHlJ.png)

## Register.php

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

$name = $_POST["name"];
$age = $_POST["age"];
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];   
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO User (name, age, username, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $name, $age, $username, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
mysqli_stmt_close($statement);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

## FetchUserData.php

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM User WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $username, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $userID, $name, $age, $username,     $password);

$user = array();

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    $user["name"] = $name;
    $user["age"] = $age;
    $user["username"] = $username;
    $user["password"] = $password;
}

echo json_encode($user);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: And who is calling those php scripts? And from where?

Comment: did you actually create a user named my_user? and you have a DB called my_db? Also take a look at the quotes you have around username etc.. You want a tick like this ' not a quote ". replace all the quote marks with '

Comment: What emulator are you using? Genymotion or the Android default emulator?

Comment: Also, I believe that it is more of a DB problem because you are actually getting an error: **Access denied for user 'my_user'@'localhost' to database 'my_db'**

Comment: @greenapps the android app is calling those php script with the server address

Comment: @Evin1_ I am using android default emulator. It looks fast to me.

Comment: Oh alright. How did you grant the privileges to the DB? Did you set it enable remote access?

Comment: @Evin1_ I used a different kind of declaration this time and all those were gone but still can't connect to database

Comment: What's the error saying now?

Comment: @apesa I tried it but not connecting. The my_user and my_db I did not create it I just follow the tutorial.......but currently my database name is **heppie**. Do you think I need to replace my_db with heppie? Thanks!

Comment: Yes. Also put your customize user and password.

Comment: Where is your Android app running on? Device or emulator? Show the complete url you use please.

Comment: @greenapps https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x0I5vJfaRIU

Comment: @Evin1_ sorry for the confusion.....try checking out also this tutorial... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x0I5vJfaRIU .....  the user and password is generated when the app user successful is registered then to be able to get in, the app user should input the correct username and password.

Comment: Just answer my questions. I'm not here to watch movies.

Comment: @greenapps Sorry if I showed you a video. I am using the android emulator. Sorry to ask again, which url are you referring to? the server address?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of localhost use this: `http://10.0.2.2`
[*Reference*](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. **  public static final String SERVER_ADDRESS = "http://10.0.2.2/heppie/"; **   but not yet working :(

Comment: 10.0.2.2 is only for apps running in an emulator. OP did not state where his app is running and should give that info.